# I can't access Drawable folders and view an asset

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

everyone. I want to access my drawable folder to get a vector asset from there. But I can't figure it out, see picture. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: whats the R import?

Comment: Make sure you added `import com.bkoubik.shopnow.R` sometimes I face the same issue, I just clean and rebuild my project and everything works

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI
 thx!

Comment: Some of your drawables are inside **drawable-v24** folder

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your imports too? It looks like you have a warning in there..